# How to reduce boilerplate code with Scala Macros in Scala 2?

Tags: scala, shapeless, scala-macros

For such code, there are many boilerplate code.

```scala
object TupleFlatten {
  import shapeless._
  import ops.tuple.FlatMapper
  import syntax.std.tuple._

  trait LowPriorityFlat extends Poly1 {
    implicit def default[T] = at[T](Tuple1(_))
  }

  object Flat extends LowPriorityFlat {
    implicit def caseTuple1[P <: Tuple1[_]](implicit fm: FlatMapper[P, Flat.type]): Flat.Case[P] {
      type Result = FlatMapper[P, Flat.type]#Out
    } =
      at[P](_.flatMap(Flat))

    implicit def caseTuple2[P <: Tuple2[_, _]](implicit fm: FlatMapper[P, Flat.type]) =
      at[P](_.flatMap(Flat))

    implicit def caseTuple3[P <: Tuple3[_, _, _]](implicit fm: FlatMapper[P, Flat.type]) =
      at[P](_.flatMap(Flat))

    implicit def caseTuple4[P <: Tuple4[_, _, _, _]](implicit fm: FlatMapper[P, Flat.type]) =
      at[P](_.flatMap(Flat))
  }
}
```

Is there any way to auto generate code like following, from `Tuple1` to `Tuple22`

```scala
implicit def caseTupleN[P <: TupleN[???]](implicit fm: FlatMapper[P, Flat.type]) =
      at[P](_.flatMap(Flat))
```

How to do that?

Comment: What about using a source generator instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Surely, you can generate implicits for example with [macro annotation](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/annotations.html)

```
import scala.annotation.{StaticAnnotation, compileTimeOnly}
import scala.language.experimental.macros
import scala.reflect.macros.blackbox

object Macros {

  @compileTimeOnly("enable macro annotations")
  class genImplicits(n: Int) extends StaticAnnotation {
    def macroTransform(annottees: Any*): Any = macro genImplicitsMacro.impl
  }

  object genImplicitsMacro {
    def impl(c: blackbox.Context)(annottees: c.Tree*): c.Tree = {
      import c.universe._
      val n = c.prefix.tree match {
        case q"new genImplicits(${n1: Int})" => n1
      }
      val implicits = (1 to n).map { k =>
        val undescores = Seq.fill(k)(tq"${TypeName("_")}")
        q"""
          implicit def ${TermName("caseTuple" + k)}[P <: _root_.scala.${TypeName("Tuple" + k)}[..$undescores]: _root_.shapeless.IsTuple](implicit
            fm: _root_.shapeless.ops.tuple.FlatMapper[P, this.type]
          ): this.Case.Aux[P, fm.Out] = this.at[P].apply[fm.Out](_.flatMap(this))
        """
      }
      annottees match {
        case q"$mods object $tname extends { ..$earlydefns } with ..$parents { $self => ..$body }" :: Nil =>
          q"""
            $mods object $tname extends { ..$earlydefns } with ..$parents { $self =>
              import _root_.shapeless.syntax.std.tuple._
              ..$implicits
              ..$body
            }
          """
      }
    }
  }
}

import Macros.genImplicits
import shapeless.Poly1

trait LowPriorityFlat extends Poly1 {
  implicit def default[T]: Case.Aux[T, Tuple1[T]] = at[T](Tuple1(_))
}

@genImplicits(4)
object Flat extends LowPriorityFlat

Flat(((1, (2, 3), (4, (5, 6, 7))), (8, 9))) // (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
```

Compilation of `Flat(((1, (2, 3), (4, (5, 6, 7))), (8, 9)))` with `@genImplicits(22)` takes too long although expansion of `@genImplicits(22)` itself is pretty fast.

Alternatively you can use code generation with [Shapeless Boilerplate](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/main/project/Boilerplate.scala), [Scala genprod](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.13.x/project/genprod.scala), [sbt-boilerplate](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-boilerplate) or [Scalameta](https://scalameta.org/).

But I can't see how this will be better than a simpler definition using just Shapeless with context bound `IsTuple` rather than upper bound

```
import shapeless.ops.tuple.FlatMapper
import shapeless.{IsTuple, Poly1}
import shapeless.syntax.std.tuple._

trait LowPriorityFlat extends Poly1 {
  implicit def default[T]: Case.Aux[T, Tuple1[T]] = at[T](Tuple1(_))
}

object Flat extends LowPriorityFlat {
  implicit def caseTuple[P: IsTuple](implicit fm: FlatMapper[P, Flat.type]): Case.Aux[P, fm.Out]  =
    at[P](_.flatMap(Flat))
}

Flat(((1, (2, 3), (4, (5, 6, 7))), (8, 9))) // (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
```

or even without bounds

```
import shapeless.ops.tuple.FlatMapper
import shapeless.{IsTuple, Poly1}

trait LowPriorityFlat extends Poly1 {
  implicit def default[T]: Case.Aux[T, Tuple1[T]] = at[T](Tuple1(_))
}

object Flat extends LowPriorityFlat {
  implicit def caseTuple[P](implicit fm: FlatMapper[P, Flat.type]): Case.Aux[P, fm.Out]  =
    at[P](fm(_))
}

Flat(((1, (2, 3), (4, (5, 6, 7))), (8, 9))) // (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
```

Please notice that using return type of implicits with type projections `Flat.Case[P] { type Result = FlatMapper[P, Flat.type]#Out }` aka `Flat.Case.Aux[P, FlatMapper[P, Flat.type]#Out]` can sometimes lead to issues with implicit resolution (unless you know what you're doing). It's better to use path-dependent types in return type of implicits `Flat.Case.Aux[P, fm.Out]`.